# AWS CLI - passing JSON object to --tags gives error

Tags: json, bash, amazon-web-services, jq, aws-cli

I'm not running the commands below on terminal directly, but I run them from a bash script.

I need to copy tags of an rds cluster instance to its snapshot. First I'm fetching the tags like this:

```
aws rds list-tags-for-resource --resource-name $cluster_arn
```

Which returns a json like this:

```
{"TagList": [{ "Key": "owner", "Value": "me" },{ "Key": "Project", "Value": "my_project" }]}
```

Instead, I pass the command above to jq to get only the list of tags:

```
cluster_tags=$(aws rds list-tags-for-resource --resource-name $cluster_arn | jq -r '.TagList')
```

Which returns:

```
[{ "Key": "owner", "Value": "me" },{ "Key": "Project", "Value": "my_project" }]
```

Then I pass these tags on creation of snapshot:

```
aws rds create-db-cluster-snapshot --db-cluster-identifier $cluster_id --db-cluster-snapshot-identifier $cluster_snapshot_id --tags $cluster_tags
```

However, I'm getting this error:

```
Error parsing parameter '--tags': Invalid JSON:
[
```

How can I solve this problem *without creating a JSON file* ?

Comment: Could you try quoting it? `"${cluster_tags}"` ?

Comment: It worked perfectly. You can put the comment below as answer so I can close the question with that answer.